# What is the proper css selector for "between x and y"?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Let's assume i have an HTML table with 20 rows and 3 cols. (20x3)

I want to paint the rows between 7 and 12 to red.

What is the proper CSS selector for it? How can i define "between" ?

Comment: `tr:nth-child(7n+4)` should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it could be

```
nth-child(n+7):nth-child(-n+12)
```

Here is a very interesting and helpful resource: http://nthmaster.com/

Just an idea, pseudocode - select rows 7 and above and style it, then select rows 12 and above and take away the style you added to rows 7 and above.

```
tr:nth-child(n+7) {...some style...}
tr:nth-child(n+12) {...negate that style...}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be the other way around, where `n+6` rule would negate the `n+12` so that the first 6 are negated back to default style?

Comment: I just did a quick test on my 2nd snippet. (The first one line selector works fine.) I believe the logic to it is that the first rule affects every tr above and including the seventh instance.  The second rule selects every tr above and including the twelfth.  I think your question might be about the order of the css defs.  If you rearrange your lines, the outcome might be different, or if you include the !important rule.  Just a thought.

Answer (score 2):

There's a way to do this using CSS 2.1 selectors, which is a bit messy looking but easy to understand. So:

```
/* First set of colours, from 1 - 6 */
table tr td { background-color: #00f; }

/* From the 7th row onwards, different colour */
table tr + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr td { background-color: #f00; }

/* From the 13th row onwards, change it back to the first colour */
table tr + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr td { background-color: #00f; }
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/pY3wS/

The reason I would use 2.1 selectors over CSS 3 selectors such as `nth-child` is because there is better support in older browsers, most notably IE 8.

Answer (score 1):

The example below paints in red rows 3 to 5 in a table using css:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
table tr:nth-child(n+3):nth-child(-n+5) {
  background-color:  #FF3366;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <table border="1">
    <tr><td>1.1</td><td>1.2</td><td>1.3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2.1</td><td>2.2</td><td>2.3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3.1</td><td>3.2</td><td>3.3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4.1</td><td>4.2</td><td>4.3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>5.1</td><td>5.2</td><td>5.3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>6.1</td><td>6.2</td><td>6.3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>7.1</td><td>7.2</td><td>7.3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>8.1</td><td>8.2</td><td>8.3</td></tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```